# can't get radio buttons to appear on page

Tags: javascript, object, radio-button

I need to make a group of 2 radio buttons in my javascript for my web app. So far I have this code:

```
    //radio buttons start
    var AddRadio = function(options){
    var _dom_element = document.createElement("radio");

        for ( var i = 0; i < options.length; i++ ) {
        var _option = document.createElement("radio");
            _option.value = options[i];
            _option.innerHTML = options[i];

            _dom_element.appendChild(_option);
            };

            this.getDomElement = function() {
                return _dom_element;
            }
    }
    //radio buttons end

var _temp_radio = new AddRadio(['Max Temp', 'Min Temp']);

container_element.appendChild(_temp_radio.getDomElement());
```

The problem is that only the 'Max Temp' and 'Min Temp' strings show up, the actual radio buttons are not there. Thanks If you can help in any way.

Comment: A radio button is an input with the type radio. There's no radio tag.

Answer (score 1):

radio buttons are

```
<input type="radio">.
```

You are creating a

```
<radio>
```

tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `<input type="radio"/>` tag.

e.g.

```
var option = document.createElement('input');
option.type = 'radio';
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp